# How can I save MediaCodec encoded bytes in AVI/MKV format using FFmpegFrameRecorder and AVPackets?

Tags: android, h.264, android-camera2, android-mediacodec, android-ffmpeg

I have encoded bytes from android `MediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(index)` and I want to use it directly to save it in **avi/mkv** format files.

To do this with `FFmpegFrameRecorder` I guess I have to create `AVPackets`.

How can I do this?
Any help will be appreciate, thx.

I am able to save it in **mp4** format file with android `MediaMuxer`:

```
myH264EncodeConsumer.setOnH264EncodeResultListener(object :
            MyH264EncodeConsumer.OnH264EncodeResultListener {
            override fun onEncodeResult(
                data: ByteArray?,
                offset: Int,
                length: Int,
                timestamp: Long,
                bufferInfo: BufferInfo
            ) {
   val outputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data, offset, length)
   muxer.pumpStream(outputBuffer, bufferInfo, true)
}
```

But I need to save it in **avi/mkv** format files.

Comment: If you can save it to a file, one option would be to use https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit library to convert that file to another format. Don't know if they provide the possibility to pass video data from a buffer, it would need more investigation.

Comment: Maybe this could be used for dynamic bytes conversion: https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Pipe-Support. Though not sure about the exact syntax for a byte array. It seems there should be some examples in their test apps.

Comment: thx for answer, yep i need to convert bytes dynamicly, convert to another file is not solution for me, because it is heavy operation and this operation is very intensive GPU intensive and too long